# Optimization of code for GEE charts

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, chart

I'm extracting spectral signatures from Sentinel 2 imagery. I need to plot the chart for a certain target area showing the signature of the area and that one of a different reference area. Then I need to plot another chart with the same reference area but with a different target area:

```
var reference = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[-84.44619213017016, 35.19851370864028],
              [-84.44619213017016, 35.16484078438886],
              [-84.40773998173266, 35.16484078438886],
              [-84.40773998173266, 35.19851370864028]]], null, false),
        {
          "label": "reference",
          "system:index": "0"
        }),
    area1 = 
    /* color: #98ff00 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[-84.00948558720141, 35.20075807419582],
              [-84.00948558720141, 35.17382159487173],
              [-83.97927318485766, 35.17382159487173],
              [-83.97927318485766, 35.20075807419582]]], null, false),
        {
          "label": "area1",
          "system:index": "0"
        }),
    area2 = 
    /* color: #0b4a8b */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[-84.62197338017016, 34.939998466506516],
              [-84.62197338017016, 34.91522804211345],
              [-84.58901439579516, 34.91522804211345],
              [-84.58901439579516, 34.939998466506516]]], null, false),
        {
          "label": "area2",
          "system:index": "0"
        });


//cloud mask
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

//dataset
var image = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
            .select('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B9', 'B11', 'B12', 'QA60')
                        .filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-06-30')
                        .median();

//                      
var image_chart = image.select('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B9', 'B11', 'B12');

//
var wl_sent2 = [442, 492, 559, 664, 704, 740, 780, 832, 864, 945, 1613, 2202];                      
                        
                        
//chart1

var area1coll = ee.FeatureCollection([reference,area1]);

var area1chart = ui.Chart.image.regions(
                                  image_chart,
                                  area1coll,
                                  ee.Reducer.mean(),
                                  10,
                                  'label',
                                  wl_sent2)
                                  .setChartType('ScatterChart');
                                  
                                  print(area1chart);
//chart2
var area2coll = ee.FeatureCollection([reference,area2]);

var area2chart = ui.Chart.image.regions(
                                  image_chart,
                                  area2coll,
                                  ee.Reducer.mean(),
                                  10,
                                  'label',
                                  wl_sent2)
                                  .setChartType('ScatterChart');
                                  
                                  print(area2chart);
```

This should be potentially repeated for a huge number of new target areas (area3, area4,...).

Is there a way to avoid to copy and paste the code for the chart generation, keeping the same reference area and iterating over the different target areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function for the chart and then repeat it for any area.
Something like this

```
// Define a function to display chart
var areachartfunc = function(area) {
  var areacoll = ee.FeatureCollection([reference, area])
  var areachart = ui.Chart.image.regions({
    image: image_chart,
    regions: areacoll ,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 10,
    seriesProperty:'label',
    xLabels:wl_sent2
  }).setChartType('ScatterChart');
  
  print(areachart)
}
// Show chart
areachartfunc(area1)
```

---

<sub>*Kindly upvote if you find this useful, it will motivate me to contribute more to the GIS community.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I run the code I get the errors: "Error generating chart: Unable to transform geometry into projection <Projection>." and "Unable to transform geometry into projection <Projection>." Should I map the function over a collection of areas (geometries)?

Comment: Hi HyPhens, sorry I didn't run the code last time. You just have to change the geometry as per your previous code and it will work just fine. I have edited my answer, kindly use it as a reference.

Comment: Thanks, now it works, so just for clarity, should I repeat the last line for every area? Such as: `areachartfunc(area1), areachartfunc(area2),`  ...  `areachartfunc(area1000)`